# Configuration with id 'ADAPTER_CONTENT' for schema 'mfp_default_schema' with version '1.0' not found

Tags: java, deployment, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I am trying to deploy an JavaSQL Adapter with Hikari Pool using MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 and Postgres 9.5

On deploying, I get the following in the log:

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0321: State change failure. Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: User code thrown exception: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:516)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:118)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:71)
at com.kloan.JavaSQLApplication.getDataSource(JavaSQLApplication.java:49)
at com.kloan.JavaSQLApplication.init(JavaSQLApplication.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at 
java.lang.RuntimeException: User code thrown exception: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:516)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:118)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:71)
    at com.kloan.JavaSQLApplication.getDataSource(JavaSQLApplication.java:49)
    at com.kloan.JavaSQLApplication.init(JavaSQLApplication.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at 
[ERROR   ] CNFSRVE115: configuration with id 'ADAPTER_CONTENT' for schema 'mfp_default_schema' with version '1.0' not found
[ERROR   ] Unable to delete configuration with id ADAPTER_CONTENT due to exception FWLSE3208E: An invalid status code "404" was returned. The response content is "{"reason":"configuration_not_found","details":"CNFSRVE115: configuration with id 'ADAPTER_CONTENT' for schema 'mfp_default_schema' with version '1.0' not found"}".
```

What is `mfp_default_schema` and where do I find it?

Comment: What version of MobileFirst and Database are you using?

Comment: I am using Mobilefirst 8.0 and postgres 9.5

Comment: @dhiraka, What is the exact v8.0 build you're using? You can find it out in the console -> hello, admin -> about.

Comment: @IdanAdar Product version: 8.0.0.00-20160809-2334

Comment: 'mfp_default_schema' is part of the MFP configuration service. The binaries of adapters are stored there. However it seems like the actual problem here is that the adapter cannot be deployed because there is an exception thrown during the adapter's init stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest DevKit build, released yesterday (September 2nd, 2016) should address this. If you are a customer, you can find your copy in IBM Fix Central. If you are an evaluator, you [can find it here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/).