# Failed on deploying adapter on IBM MobileFirst Platform 8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mfp

I'm tearing my hair off with IBM MobileFirst Platform 8.0 on deploying the adapter.

I'm quite new to this platform and trying to following the instruction here 
http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/creating-adapters/#creating-adapters-using-mobilefirst-cli

I installed the mfp server, the mfpdev-cli, installed maven, created an adapter (which is just a default adapter). Then, run

```
mfpdev adapter build
```

The operation was success.

However, when I tried to deploy to the mfp server using mfpdev, there was an error in the console and the adapter was not deployed.

Here's the error :

```
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SampleAdapter 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.2018021101:deploy (default-cli) @ SampleAdapter ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.529 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2561-03-08T19:20:29+07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/112M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.2018021101:deploy (default-cli) on project SampleAdapter: Unexpected response from http://localhost:9080/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/adapters -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Error deploying adapter
undefined
Error: An error occurred during an attempt to deploy the adapter. See the 
preceding messages for details.
```

And when I looked to the mfp server log, it showed this error.

```
[ERROR   ] RuntimeMBeanCallable.call() exception                                                                        

java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException                                                                    
[err] java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException                                                                    
[err]   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy342.changeDeploymentState(Unknown Source)                                                
[err]   at com.ibm.mfp.admin.actions.ArtifactDeploymentTransaction.prepareMBean(ArtifactDeploymentTransaction.java:822) 
[err]   at com.ibm.mfp.admin.actions.util.RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller$RuntimeMBeanCallale.call(RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller.java:76)                                                                                                      
[err]   at com.ibm.mfp.admin.actions.util.RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller.callSynchronouslyRuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller.java:206)                                                                                                             
[err]   at com.ibm.mfp.admin.actions.util.RuntimeMBeanPoolCaller.callRuntimeMBeans(RuntimeMBeanPoolCaller.java:91)      
.
.
.
.
[err]   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)                                     
[err]   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:501)                                      
[err]   at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:914)                                                           
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)                                                  
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)                                
[err]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)                        
[err]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)                                                             
[err]   at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)                                      
[err]   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1900)                                        
[err]   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)                                    
[err]   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)                                           
[err]   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)                                     
[err]   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)                                        
[err]   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)                                    
[err]   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)                                           
[err]   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)                                             
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.server.rest.JSONSerializationHelper.readObject(JSONSerializationHelper.java:69)     
[err]   at [internal classes]                                                                                           
[err]   ... 102 more                                                                                                    
[ERROR   ] Unable to delete configuration with id ADAPTER_CONTENT due to exception FWLSE3208E: An invalid status code "404" was returned. 
The response content is "{"reason":"configuration_not_found","details":"CNFSRVE115: configuration with id 'ADAPTER_CONTENT' for schema 'mfp_default_schema' with version '1.0' not found"}".
```

However, I did skim back to the server starting log, there seemed to have some [err], which I'm not sure whether it is an error or not.

```
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.CookieParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the file:/D:/MobileFirst/mfp server/usr/servers/mfp/apps/mfp-push-service.war location rather than from a product class loader.
[err] 670  PushPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 2.4.1
[err] 1363  PushPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DerbyDictionary".
[err] 2688  PushPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Connected to Apache Derby version 10.10 using JDBC driver Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver version 10.11.1.1 - (1616546).
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application mfp started in 47.549 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application imfpush started in 49.088 seconds.
[19:12:51,128][WARN ][org.elasticsearch.bootstrap] JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
[err] 24634  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-5] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 2.4.1
[err] 24634  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-5] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DerbyDictionary" (Apache Derby 10.11.1.1 - (1616546) ,Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)).
[err] 24650  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-5] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Connected to Apache Derby version 10.10 using JDBC driver Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver version 10.11.1.1 - (1616546).
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application analytics-service started in 58.394 seconds.
```

I couldn't find any solution or resource regarded to this problem. There are just some few thread talking about this but they couldn't manage to solve it either.

[Configuration with id 'ADAPTER_CONTENT' for schema 'mfp_default_schema' with version '1.0' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39124552/configuration-with-id-adapter-content-for-schema-mfp-default-schema-with-ver)

and

https://www.cpume.com/question/fezseeoz-unable-to-delete-configuration-with-id-adapter-content-due-to-exception-fwlse320.html

I also tried to deploy from MobileFirst Application Web Console. It also failed.

My machine env are as follow:

```
OS : Win7 SP1
JDK :  1.8.0_60-b27
Maven  :  3.5.2
MFP Server : 8.0.0.00-20180220-083852
mfpdev-cli : 8.0.0-2017102406
```

Anyone has experienced this before? 
All helps and suggestions would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Can you please let us know the 1) exact server version 2) the mfpdev-cli version?
Also, is this problem specific to a single adapter or across any adapter you create?
In the server logs ( of FFDC) do you see DB connection or any such error messages?

Comment: Check your JAVA_HOME environment variable. Like: JAVA_HOME  - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151

Comment: 1) MFP Server's version is 8.0.0.00-20180220-083852
2) mfpdev-cli 's version is 8.0.0-2017102406


*** The problem happens too all adapters deployment I've tried so far. Actually I never managed to deploy successfully anytime before. 

*** I couldn't find the db connection error message. Only this line seems relate to derby connection

___[err] 1242  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-7] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Connected to Apache Derby version 10.10 using JDBC driver Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver version 10.11.1.1 - (1616546).

Comment: my JAVA_HOME points to the correct path. It's JAVA_HOME=D:\java\jdk1.8.0_60

Comment: I think the issue might not be just for adapters, it could be for other artifacts too. Can you try to register an app from the Console and see if the app registration is successful?

Comment: The app can be deployed with success. Only the adapter that failed.

Comment: Since no adapters are working for you, can you please provide one of your adapter ( a dummy one will do), so that we can test.

Comment: I recently debugged a very similar issue. After putting things together piece by piece , I figured that there was a code block which included classes from javax.mail.*. While this built fine, deploy threw the exact same exception as yours. Finally, i added javax.mail dependency directly in pom.xml and it started working fine. Could your case be similar? May be there is a class usage ( anything) that gets built, but server does not have it. ?
You can add method by method to see the breaking point. Or you could share an adapter that does not work and I will take a look

Comment: First, I'm pretty sure those "[err] ... INFO" messages are INFO logging, not error.

Comment: It is important that the CLI version is lesser than the server version. If the adapter is built on a CLI version that is higher than the server version, such adapter deployment failures occur.

Comment: the cli version is already lower than mfp, the problem is still there

Comment: It seems that the issue could be happening because of the Bhuddhist Calendar type set for the OS. So changing the  Windows setting to use Gregorian calendar where DevKit is installed fixed the issue:
    Click the Start button .
    Click Control Panel.
    Skip this step if you do NOT have the view set to Category: Click Clock, Language, and Region.
    1. Click Region and Language.
    2. Click the Formats tab. 
    3. In the Format drop-down list, select English United States